# C++ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, recursion, memory-leaks

Given an integer, we need to find the super digit of the integer.

We define super digit of an integer `x` using the following rules:

If `x` has only 1 digit, then its super digit is `x`
Otherwise, the super digit of  is equal to the super digit of the digit-sum of `x`. Here, digit-sum of a number is defined as the sum of its digits.

Example:

```
super_digit(9875) = super_digit(9+8+7+5) 

= super_digit(29) 

= super_digit(2+9)

= super_digit(11)

= super_digit(1+1)

= super_digit(2)

= 2
```

**Task:**
You are given two numbers `n` and `k`. You have to calculate the super digit of `p`.`p` is created when number `n` is concatenated `k` times.

My Code to solve this problem is shown below.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int superDigit(string n, int k)
{
    int res=0;
    for (int x = 0; x < n.length(); x++)
    {
        res += n[x] - '0';
    }
    res = k * res;
    if (res < 10)
        return res;
    else
        return superDigit(to_string(res),1);
}

int main() {
    string n;
    int k;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> k;
    cout << superDigit(n, k)<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code seems to work normally for all small numbers, but when `n` 
is `1e100000-1` and `k` is `100000`, the program returns the following error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>
> what():  std::bad_alloc

I think it's a memory leak, but how do I fix this. Where is the leak happening?

Comment: It's not because of memory leak. It was unable to allocate the specified amount of memory. More info can be found here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc

Comment: Use a debugger. It will stop at the point that throws the exception. Very useful.

Comment: Good to know that, but how can I solve this.

Comment: The first thing would probably be eliminating recursion.

Comment: Unrelated: It appears you do not know what `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` does, so I recommend giving [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) a read before it turns into a bad habit.

Comment: `1e100000-1` is not a valid specification of an integer.

Comment: x+x+x+x+x can be reduced to just 5*x.

Comment: **Unable to reproduce**. Are you sure this is the code you used?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf `1e100000-1` is just for understanding. While compiling, I have to write 100000 consecutive 9's. Obviously I can't write that long number in a console, so I put the input directly in the code and comment out `cin >> n`

Comment: @Follij: 10^5 * 10^5 = 10^10 = 100 billion characters. One billion is about 1 GByte. How many GBytes of main memory does your PC have? Have you considered replacing string concatenation with, like, simple multiplication?

Comment: Ow. That's a pretty big string and a whole lot of iterations to process it. Running out of memory is a distinct possibility even with controlled recursion.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ok, let me try to fix it.

Comment: Do you mean that you actually typed `1e100000-1` at the input prompt?

Comment: @M.M `While compiling, I have to write 100000 consecutive 9's. Obviously I can't write that long number in a console, so I put the input directly in the code and comment out cin >> n` so no.

Comment: **−1** The presented code is no longer the one producing the issue asked about.

Comment: @Follj in that case you should post the exact code causing the problem output

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are taking `n` as `1e10000-1`. That is about `1e10000` characters long. Assuming each character is about `1` byte size. Then,

> `1e10000 bytes = 1e9997 kilobytes = 1e9994 MB = 1e9994 GB = 1e9991 TB`
>   As you can see it is insanely large.

Comment: Re "That is about 1e10000 characters long." Consider how large the source code would have to be for that specification, assuming that the OP put it directly there, as indicated. Is there anything about that that strikes you as, well, noteworthy?

Comment: I fixed the code (see above), but I get the wrong result `-194313216`.

Comment: It's `1e100000`, not `1e10000`

Comment: @Follj: In future, please don't fundamentally change the question when an answer has been posted. Happily this answer was wrong. But if it was a good answer you would just have invalidated it, negating that person's work.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'll keep that in mind. I am sorry, I am new here.

Comment: Using Akash Kumar, I finally solved the problem, but then I have a problem with `int` so I replaced every int with `uint64_t`.

Comment: **−1** To counter the OP's selection as solution, for this nonsense (wrong) answer.